# How to retrieve value from SQL server DB?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The following query works fine:

```
select ProductNumber,Name,Color,ListPrice 
from Production.Product 
where ProductNumber = 'AR-5381'
```

Where as when,
I'm writing my code like following to retrieve value from SQL sever:

```
declare @ProductNum nvarchar
set @ProductNum = 'AR-5381'
select ProductNumber,Name,Color,ListPrice 
from Production.Product 
where ProductNumber = @ProductNum
```

I'm not able to get the values. But ProductNumber('AR-5381') is present in the table.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable is declared with default length which is 1.

`nvarchar` without specifying length means `nvarchar(1)`

so following `nvarchar` varaible only store first character in the string because its length is one.

```
declare @ProductNum nvarchar
set @ProductNum = 'AR-5381'
SELECT @ProductNum
```

Output
A

```
declare @ProductNum nvarchar(2)
set @ProductNum = 'AR-5381'
SELECT @ProductNum
```

Output
AR

You should specify some length like.

```
declare @ProductNum nvarchar(255)
set @ProductNum = 'AR-5381'
select ProductNumber,Name,Color,ListPrice 
from Production.Product 
where ProductNumber =@ProductNum
```